# If "if" is the last control statement in function and its block always executes "return", then should I use "else"?

Tags: function, if-statement, language-agnostic, return

Consider this code (written in C to demonstrate the problem):

```
int foo1(int a)
{
    if(a)
         return 33;
    return 22;
}

int foo2(int a)
{
    if(a)
         return 33;
    else
         return 22;
}
```

As you can see, `foo1(int a)` does exactly the same as `foo2(int a)`. `foo1(int a)` is shorter, however I get the impression that `foo2(int a)` is just more logical (that's only my impression). Which one is better? Is it good to use `else` with `if` that is the last control statement in function code and its block always executes `return`?

Comment: I think this is somewhat subjective and that there's no clear "best" answer. By the way, a third option would be to use the ternary conditional operator: `return a? 33 : 22;`.

Comment: @templatetypedef indeed, but as a general rule, only foobars would consider foo2 superior.

Comment: @templatetypedef I made this example to show the core of the problem as simply as I could. However, in practice both code blocks can contain other instructions that may be impossible to describe with `return a? 33 : 22`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about C specifically, but in C# at least the convention is to omit the `else` for any `if` conditions that immediately return. The reasoning is that the `else` is already implied, so explicitly adding it is not only redundant, but increases the nesting level of following code, thus making the code harder to read. Take a look at the following code as an example.

```
public int Test()
{
    if (condition)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        var ex1 = doCmd1();
        var ex2 = doCmd2();
        var result = ex1 + ex2;
        return result;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Here I'm printing before returning");
    return -1;
}
```

If you take just a very brief glance at this code, you might think there are three ways the method can exit. However, that's not the case - it can only exit in two ways. Everything outside the `if-else` is completely unreachable. Now, here's the same code, but without the extra `else`:

```
public int Test()
{
    if (condition)
        return 0;

    var ex1 = doCmd1();
    var ex2 = doCmd2();
    var result = ex1 + ex2;
    Console.WriteLine("Here I'm printing before returning");
    return result;
}
```

This is much more clear to read and quickly identify what the results of the operation are going to be.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that foo1 is superior. The lines

```
    return 22;
}
```

as the end of the function trumps any other readability issue.

foo2 should FAPP be considered written as

```
int foo2(int a)
{
    if(a){
         return 33;
    } else {
         return 22;
    }
}
```

add some 20 or so lines of code before the `return 22;` line and it is a source of obscure bugs and hindering readability.