# Pro/contra of using "else" if the then-clause exits the method anyways

Tags: java, if-statement, return

Which of these two is the "better" method and why?

```
if(list.isEmpty()) {
    return;
} else {
    [...]
}
```

vs.

```
if(list.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}

[...]
```

Comment: `if (!list.isEmpty()) { ... do stuff }`

Comment: I would definitely go with the second option. Return early - there's no reason to continue on if you've already got invalid data/conditions. Another benefit to doing it this way is that nesting is reduced, making for more readable code. @khelwood's method, though perfectly valid, indents the whole method by one tab.

Comment: @khelwood this would make my code less easy to read since I only want to return false if an "error" occurs e.g. when the given list is empty...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057896/if-if-is-the-last-control-statement-in-function-and-its-block-always-executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` in the first approach is redundant, because of the `return` statement.

For situations when you stop evaluation early on a certain condition the second approach is better, because it decreases the level of nesting. This becomes especially important when early stops with `return`s or `throw`s are done several times:

```
if (arg1 == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
} else {
    if (arg2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
        if (arg3 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            ... // Payload code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

is less readable than

```
if (arg1 == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
if (arg2 == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
if (arg3 == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
... // Payload code goes here
```

Examples above use `throw`, but the argument for `return` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you type:

```
if(list.isEmpty()) {
    return;
} else {
    [...]
}
```

You can add some code to handle the "else" block if first block is not true, and when you use:

```
if(list.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}

[...]
```

You are actually saying: I don't want to do anything if it fails.

Comment: This is just an explanation of what seems to be obvious by the code. If you're going to answer an opinion-based question; please give your opinion.